# Searchable Dictionary V2 Sample How to View & Edit Database Tables/Records?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I just downloaded Searchable Dictionary V2 which is at
sdk\samples\android-11\SearchableDictionary

How do i view the dictionary's database table and records with a tools like DB Browser for SQLite or the SQLite Manager in Firefox?

I notice that it load the words from res->raw->definitions.txt. How do I add new words directly into the database table instead?

I'm new to android & sqllite and actually I don't quite understand why the sample need to load words from a file instead of directly store the words in it's database table?

Comment: becuase it is more clear than using pre populated database ... it also show onCreate of helper usage ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`How do i view the dictionary's database table and records with a tools like DB Browser for SQLite` Install the SQLiteBrowser plugin from Questoid (it will appear in the DDMS/FileBrowser view).
Select the db from the `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db` path in that view.

`or the SQLite Manager in Firefox?` Export the db from the `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db` path in the DDMS/FileBrowser view to a path of your choice on your hard drive, then happily view/play with it in FireFox.